# psql client old 9.2 version

Tags: postgresql, centos, psql

How to switch into psql version 11 ?

root#   psql -V -> psql (PostgreSQL) 9.2.24
user@ psql -V -> psql (PostgreSQL) 11.6

```
ps -ef | grep postgres -> /usr/pgsql-11/bin/postmaster -D /var/lib/pgsql/11/data
```

Comment: `yum remove postgresql92`

Comment: Perhaps you can try `/usr/pgsql-11/bin/psql`